# If $A\in B(X)$ is a Fredholm operator, is it true that $nA$ is a Fredholm operator

Tags: functional-analysis

Suppose $A\in B(X)$ is a Fredholm operator, is it true that $nA$ is a Fredholm operator, where $n$ is scalar

---

I guess the answer is wrong, Fredholm operator forms an open set. Since open set is absorbent, if the statement is true, then all bounded operators are Fredholm operator. But I don't know how to prove it directly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$A \in B(X)$ is a Fredholm operator if

1. $\dim \,(\ker A) < \infty$,
2. $\dim \, (X/\operatorname{im} A) < \infty$.

There's also 3. $\operatorname{im} A$ is closed, but that condition is redundant.

If $A\in B(X)$ is a Fredholm operator and $n$ is a scalar, then $nA \in B(X)$, and if $n \neq 0$, we have $\ker\,(nA) = \ker A$ and $\operatorname{im} \,(nA) = \operatorname{im} A$, so $nA$ is  Fredholm operator. If $n = 0$, then $nA = 0$, and that is a Fredholm operator if and only if $\dim X < \infty$.

Comment: "Fredholm = inverible modulo compact" works even shorter.

Comment: @89085731 Among the scalar multiples of a Fredholm operator, $0$ is the only one that need not be a Fredholm operator (when $0$ is a Fredholm operator, every operator is one). But on infinite spaces, there are lots of continuous linear operators that aren't Fredholm. For example every continuous operator of finite rank.

Answer (score 1):

$A$ Fredholm [if and only if](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atkinson's_theorem) $\exists B\in B(X)$ such that $AB-I$ and $BA-I$ are compact operators. Now for $n\ne 0$ taking $\frac{1}{n}B$ proves that $nA$ is Fredholm.